# How to test that a Phoenix socket is terminated?

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I'm looking for a way to test that a socket gets terminated. The code under test does this:

```
def handle_in("logout", _payload, socket) do
  {:stop, :logout, socket |> assign(:user, nil)}
end
```

And my test code (adapted from http://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/try-catch-and-rescue.html#exits) does this:

```
test "logout terminates the socket", %{socket: socket} do
  try do
    push socket, "logout"
  catch
    huh -> IO.puts("Caught something #{IO.inspect huh}")
    :exit, what -> IO.puts("Caught :exit #{IO.inspect what}")
  end
  assert_receive {:DOWN, monitor_ref, _, :normal}
end
```

but when I run the tests, I get this:

```
1) test logout without login terminates the socket (Main.AuthChannelTest)
   test/channels/auth_channel_test.exs:47
   ** (EXIT from #PID<0.505.0>) :logout

.....09:06:41.139 [error] GenServer #PID<0.507.0> terminating
** (stop) :logout
```

How *should* I be testing for socket closure?

Answer (score 4):

The message sent when a process you monitor goes down is `{:DOWN, ref, :process, pid, reason}`, so

1. You should have a 5 tuple in the `assert_receive`
2. You should terminate with the reason `:normal`, if you want to match with the reason `:normal`. If you do this, you won't have to catch any exit signals (see below if you do want to exit with `:logout`).

The following works for me:

```
def handle_in("logout", _payload, socket) do
  {:stop, :normal, socket |> assign(:user, nil)}
end
```

```
test "...", %{socket: %{channel_pid: channel_pid} = socket} do
  monitor_ref = Process.monitor(channel_pid)
  push socket, "logout", %{}
  assert_receive {:DOWN, ^monitor_ref, _, _, :normal}
end
```

If you for some reason *do* want to exit the socket with the reason `:logout`, you'll also have to trap exits as any reason other than `:normal` causes an exit signal to be sent to all processes linked to a process, and in the tests, the process running the tests *is* linked to the `socket.channel_pid`. The following works:

```
def handle_in("logout", _payload, socket) do
  {:stop, :logout, socket |> assign(:user, nil)}
end
```

```
test "...", %{socket: %{channel_pid: channel_pid} = socket} do
  Process.flag(:trap_exit, true)
  monitor_ref = Process.monitor(channel_pid)
  push socket, "logout", %{}
  assert_receive {:DOWN, ^monitor_ref, _, _, :logout} 
end
```

Comment: OK, thanks. I've decided that `:normal` is an adequate reason, so I think I'm set for now.

Answer (score 0):

Received a good answer via Elixir Slack channel:

Revise the test code to trap exit signals. Here's the updated test that's working as intended:

```
test "logout terminates the socket", %{socket: socket} do
  Process.flag(:trap_exit, true)
  push socket, "logout"
  socket_pid = socket.channel_pid
  assert_receive {:EXIT, ^socket_pid, :logout}
end
```

Note that there's still console log noise with this, so I have since changed the exit reason to `:normal` and all is quiet.