# How to test channel with Phoenix.ChannelTest.close/2

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, phoenix-channels, ex-unit

I have a test that starts up a socket connection and subscribes and joins a topic. I then push a message to the channel which does some work and persist some data. I then use ChannelTest.close/2 on the socket which simulates the client closing the connection. I would then like to modify the manipulated data and create another socket connection to test some behaviour.

My issue is ChannelTest.close/2 causes my test to fail and returns `** (EXIT from #PID<0.558.0>) shutdown: :closed`. How can I prevent this from happening?

Here's some relevant code

```
defmodule PlexServer.EmpireChannelTest do  

  use PlexServer.ChannelCase

  alias PlexServer.EmpireChannel
  alias PlexServer.EmpireTemplate
  alias PlexServer.EmpireInstance

  setup do
    ...

    {:ok, _, socket} =
      socket("user_id", %{})
      |> subscribe_and_join(EmpireChannel,
        "empire:#{empire.id}",
        %{"guardian_token" => jwt})

    {:ok, socket: socket, empire: empire, jwt: jwt}
  end

  test "research infrastructure", %{socket: socket, empire: empire, jwt: jwt} do
    ...

    ref = push socket, "command", request
    assert_reply ref, :ok, _, 1000

    close(socket) #fails here

    ...
  end
end

defmodule PlexServer.UserSocket do
  use Phoenix.Socket
  use Guardian.Phoenix.Socket

  ## Channels
  # channel "rooms:*", PlexServer.RoomChannel
  channel "empire:*", PlexServer.EmpireChannel
  channel "user:*", PlexServer.UserChannel

  ## Transports
  transport :websocket, Phoenix.Transports.WebSocket

  def connect(_params,_) do
    :error
  end

  def id(_socket), do: nil
end


defmodule PlexServer.EmpireChannel do
  use PlexServer.Web, :channel
  use Guardian.Channel

  alias PlexServer.EmpireInstance
  alias PlexServer.EmpireServer

  ...

  def join("empire:" <> empire_id, %{claims: _claims, resource: user}, socket) do
    ...
    #Starts a process through a supervisor here
  end

  def join("empire:" <> _, _, _socket) do
    {:error, data_error(:auth, "not authorized, did you pass your jwt?")}
  end

  # Channels can be used in a request/response fashion
  # by sending replies to requests from the client
  def handle_in("ping", payload, socket) do
    {:reply, {:ok, payload}, socket}
  end

  def handle_in("show", _, socket) do    
    ...
  end

  def handle_in("command", request, socket) do
    ...
  end

  def handle_in("remove", _, socket) do
    ...
  end

  def handle_in("ship_templates", _, socket) do
    ...
  end
end
```

Following the answer linked in the comments I added some code:

```
Process.flag(:trap_exit, true)
monitor_ref = Process.monitor(socket.channel_pid)
close(socket)
```

Now I get a different error message: `** (exit) exited in: GenServer.call(PlexServer.EmpireSupervisor, {:terminate_child, :empire4}, :infinity)
         ** (EXIT) no process`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to test that a Phoenix socket is terminated?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39879632/how-to-test-that-a-phoenix-socket-is-terminated)

Comment: I believe my answer here would work with this question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/39880065/320615.

Comment: @Dogbert I edited my question. It didn't solve my issue.

Comment: That seems like an unrelated error. The following test passes for me: https://gist.github.com/66f969eae3cf361740cb77a7e9773208. Can you try replicating the error in a new Phoenix app or post more code and the full error messages so I can try replicating it?

Comment: @Dogbert yeah I believe you're right. In my channel join I start up a process through a supervisor and that must be whats going wrong. I added more code but I'll investigate. This question seems to have been answered with the duplicate though.

Comment: I think you should have an option here on this page to instantly accept my "Close as Duplicate" vote.

Comment: @Dogbert Hmm I don't see that option any where. I added my vote to have it closed.